# onSizeChanged called multiple times, when to paint?

Tags: android, android-custom-view

I paint a content of custom View in `onMeasure` method. But I realized that this method is called multiple times. What is a correct way to paint my View? I rely on view dimensions.

```
01-11 21:44:32.696 28039-28039/ D/TilesView: onMeasure(MeasureSpec: EXACTLY 704, MeasureSpec: EXACTLY 1070)
01-11 21:44:32.696 28039-28039/ D/TilesView: onMeasure(MeasureSpec: EXACTLY 704, MeasureSpec: EXACTLY 1070)
01-11 21:44:32.700 28039-28039/ D/TilesView: onSizeChanged(704, 1070, 0, 0)
01-11 21:44:32.801 28039-28039/ D/TilesView: draw 82 ms
01-11 21:44:32.930 28039-28039/ D/TilesView: onDraw()
01-11 21:44:33.100 28039-28039/ D/TilesView: onMeasure(MeasureSpec: EXACTLY 704, MeasureSpec: EXACTLY 958)
01-11 21:44:33.100 28039-28039/ D/TilesView: onMeasure(MeasureSpec: EXACTLY 704, MeasureSpec: EXACTLY 958)
01-11 21:44:33.101 28039-28039/ D/TilesView: onSizeChanged(704, 958, 1070, 704)
01-11 21:44:33.118 28039-28039/ D/TilesView: draw 9 ms
01-11 21:44:33.124 28039-28039/ D/TilesView: onDraw()
```

Answer (score 0):

All the display activities should be done in the onDraw() method.

Comment: onDraw is called twice as well

Comment: onDraw() is the correct place for this. It could be called multiple times depending on events like changes in device orientation or calls to invalidate() in your code.